# How to overlap multi-year dataset with NVD3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm getting quite stuck on how to configure my NVD3 graph with my dataset.

It is a simple line chart and my dataset contains values spanning many years. I need to show these values in a condensed form, i.e. the graph will show only 1 year (Jan -> Dec) with each year in the dataset being a separate line on the graph.

Currently, if I graph the dataset I get all years plotted (e.g Jan 2008 -> Dec 2010).
Here is a jsFiddle of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/xABVB/

I can't work out where to change the NVD3/D3 setup. Would this be defined in the x-axis domain or range? or is it the Tick count that needs to be modified?

Preferably, I would like my dataset to remain as Date objects.

A quick overview of my code (taken from the jsFiddle):

```
var chart, years;

chart = nv.models.lineChart().x(function(dataPoint) {
    return dataPoint[0];
}).y(function(dataPoint) {
    return dataPoint[1];
});
chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Value').tickFormat(function(value) {
    return value;
});
chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Date').rotateLabels(-45).tickFormat(function(date) {
    return d3.time.format('%b %d')(new Date(date));
});

values = getValues();

if (values === void 0) {
    d3.select(".target svg").datum([]).call(chart);
} else {
    years = [];
    _.each(values, function(element, index, list) {
        return years.push({
            key: element[0][0].getFullYear() + " Year",
            values: element
        });
    });
    d3.select(".target svg").datum(years).call(chart);
}

nv.addGraph(chart);


// Dummy data covering 3 consecutive years.
function getValues(){
    return [[[new Date("2008-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"),10],[new Date("2008-02-29T00:00:00.000Z"),20],[new Date("2008-03-24T00:00:00.000Z"),30],[new Date("2008-04-22T00:00:00.000Z"),40],[new Date("2008-05-19T00:00:00.000Z"),50]],

[[new Date("2009-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"),20],[new Date("2009-02-30T00:00:00.000Z"),30],[new Date("2009-03-22T00:00:00.000Z"),40],[new Date("2009-04-27T00:00:00.000Z"),50],[new Date("2009-05-30T00:00:00.000Z"),60]],

[[new Date("2010-01-06T23:00:00.000Z"),30],[new Date("2010-02-05T23:00:00.000Z"),35],[new Date("2010-03-31T23:00:00.000Z"),45],[new Date("2010-04-30T23:00:00.000Z"),50],[new Date("2010-05-29T23:00:00.000Z"),60]]]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be to set all input dates to the same year:

```
chart = nv.models.lineChart().x(function(dataPoint) {
    point = new Date(dataPoint[0])
    point.setFullYear(2000)
    return point;
})
```

Then, you should remove the year from the displayed date (as you already do):

```
chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Date').rotateLabels(-45).tickFormat(function(date) {
    return d3.time.format('%b %d')(new Date(date));

});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/xABVB/3/

Comment: Interesting solution - quite simple. I'll try this out tomorrow hopefully.